# Netcat Replacement

Tags: server, file-transfer, netcat

When creating a netcat-like program how do I get that file onto a server? It seemed like the reason for creating a netcat-like program was to be able to use it to run commands, get files and connect to ports.

So it seems like it's necessary to have it on the server in order to put it on the server?

I'm probably just really confused.

Comment: Why do you need it on "the server"? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use another program to load it initially.  For example, you might ssh in.

It is also possible that you'd have physical access to the server and could install the first file transfer program manually, or as part of the intial OS install.

Not all interactions have to be done remotely.  Otherwise, your intuition would be right -- we'd have a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Thank you! I should have known ssh was an option.